# For each $n\ge2$ calculate the determinant of this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics, determinant

The matrix is

$\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & \cdots&0&1 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots&1&0 \\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0&1&\cdots&0&0\\
1&0&\cdots&0&0
\end{matrix}\right)$

For example for $n=2$ the matrix is

$\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 1  \\
1 & 0 
\end{matrix}\right)$

For $n=3$

$\left(\begin{matrix}
0 &0& 1  \\
0&1&0\\
1 &0&0 
\end{matrix}\right)$

So by making some calculations I noticed that the same value of the determinant is repeated at regular intervals. In particular $-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1... $ for $n=2,3,4,5,6,7...$. I have some difficulties in formalising this result and maybe answer with a closed formula (?) to determine what is the determinant for for whatever $n$ I choose. Any hint?

Comment: Are you familiar with calculating the determinant by minor expansion? Or maybe how switching columns affect the determinant?

Comment: @Stefan4024 Yes, I used it to calculate the determinant of some example matrix.

Comment: If you want a closed form, you could write $(-1)^{\lceil (n-1)/2\rceil}$ where $\lceil n \rceil$ is the ``ceiling function,'' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions

Comment: One simple way to prove the formula would be to consider the subsequences of even and odd numbers separately, and then induct on each. At each step you need to add two rows.

Answer (score 1):

A basic property of determinants is that swapping two columns of the matrix reverses the sign of the determinant. Observe that you can obtain this matrix from the identity by swapping column $1$ with column $n$, column $2$ with column $n-1$, and so on. This means that the determinant of this matrix must be equal to $\pm1$, with the sign depending on how many swaps were required: If $n$ is even, then $n/2$ swaps are done; if $n$ is odd, it’s $(n-1)/2$, since the central column remains untouched. This can be written succinctly using the floor function: the determinant is equal to $(-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor}$.

Floor and ceiling can be inconvenient to manipulate in expressions. We really only care about the parity of the number of swaps—whether it’s even or odd—so you could use any other simple function of $n$ that has the same parity as $\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor$ such as $n(n-1)/2$.

Comment: This point of view is really interesting and I want to try to answer the question by following it. I’ll be honest I don’t really understand the relationship between the value of the determinant and the number of swaps I need to do to obtain a certain matrix. For example: if $n=2$ I just need to swap the first column with the second of the identity matrix. So how can I exactly use this result to determine the sign of the determinant? Could you be more precise? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $A^2 = I_n$ where $I_n$ is the identity matrix of size $n$. Therefore, A is diagonizable and all eigenvalues of A are either $1$ or $-1$. Let $k$ be the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $1$ and $l$ the multiplicity of $-1$. We have $\det(A) = (-1)^l$ and $k +l =n$. Taking the trace of $A$, we have $k-l=0$ if $n$ is even, and $k-l=1$ if $n$ is odd. Therefore $\det(A) = (-1)^{n/2}$ if $n$ is even, and $\det(A)=(-1)^{(n-1)/2}$ otherwise. And it is always true that $\det(A) = (-1)^{n(n-1)/2}$

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Let $d_n$ the desired determinant. Expand it along the first line you get

$$d_n=(-1)^{n+1}d_{n-1}=(-1)^{n-1}d_{n-1}$$
hence by induction
$$d_n=(-1)^{\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}k}d_2=(-1)^{{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k}}=(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer but  I'm trying to figure out why the exponent becomes $n-1$ instead of $n+1$

Comment: We have  $(-1)^{n+1}=(-1)^{n-1}$ because $n+1$ and $n-1$ have the same parity: even or odd.